# nautilus browse network remove stored password?

Tags: nautilus, seahorse

I pressed enter in the prompt for username and pass, while trying to
view a pc (with windows) in my local network.

I tried to use seahorse to remove the stored data but I could not find the
entry,

I am using ubuntu 14.04...

Answer (score 2):

Open <kbd>Passwords and Keys</kbd> and search in the search field on the top right corner for the host name of your Windows machine.

You can remove the entry with a right-click. If there is no entry the password is not stored.

To save username and password you have to use the check box in the connection dialog in nautilus.